# What is the difference between "s3:PutObject*" and "s3:PutObject"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Whats the difference in AWS policies when * is at the end of the action and when there is no *(star):

```
"s3:PutObject*"
```

vs.

```
"s3:PutObject"
```

Comment: * is a wildcard, the first one matches all potential different kinds of s3:PutObject... actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one matches the actions `s3:PutObject` as well as `s3:PutObjectAcl`, `s3:PutObjectLegalHold`, basically logically speaking `s3:PutObject...Anything` or for short `s3:PutObject*`.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html for a full list.

The second one only matches `s3:PutObject`, nothing more, nothing less.